# Wrong Kafka consumer_offset

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper, confluent-platform

I am currently using the confluent platform community license. I started Zookeeper, Kafka and the schema-registry - all are used in local mode. However when starting the schema-registry for the first time, 50 messages are sent and stored inside the __consumer_offset topic (__consumer_offsets-0 to __consumer_offsets-49). Those messages are stored in the kafka-logs and when I am trying to start the services again, it fails. To be more precise: Zookeeper works but Kafka fails with the error:

"ERROR Shutdown broker because all log dirs have failed".

As suggested in some other posts I deleted the log.dirs directory referenced in the zookeeper.properties file and the log.dirs directory referenced in the server.properties file. After doing this I can start kafka again without any error - but the 50 messages are stored in __consumer_offset again when starting the schema-registry and after stopping kafka and trying to start kafka again it fails with the same error.

Any help is greatly appreciated. :)

EDIT:

Above that error theres another error saying:

"ERROR Failed to clean up log for _schemas-0 in dir /mnt/c/Users/Username/Desktop/Big_Data/confluent-6.0.0/kafka-logs due to IOException (kafka.server.LogDirFailureChannel) java.io.IOException: Invalid argument"

and also two warnings:

"WARN [ReplicaManager broker=0] Stopping serving replicas in dir /mnt/c/Users/Username/Desktop/Big_Data/confluent-6.0.0/kafka-logs (kafka.server.ReplicaManager)"

and

"WARN [ReplicaManager broker=0] Broker 0 stopped fetcher for partitions __consumer_offsets-22, ... (all of the 50 offsets are then listed)"

Comment: The schema registry doesn't commit offsets, so I don't think that topic is the problem

Comment: @OneCricketeer thanks for the quick reply! Any idea on what can cause the problem then?

Comment: Is it only the schema registry causing the issue? Could you test with any other consumer? By "50 messages", I assume you mean 1 message per partition, which seems strange because I thought a group offset commit would only be a single message to one partition

Comment: @OneCricketeer thanks again for the reply! :) I tested it again and used Apache Nifi as consumer (Processor: "ConsumeKafkaRecord_2_0) and its the same behavior as with the schema registry. So I guess you are correct - its not the schema registry causing the error. Also its indeed 1 message per partition as you suggested. I also tried NiFi als Producer. There I get 50 __transaction_state messages, so again 1 message per partition.

Comment: Alright. In that case, is there only that one error line in the broker logs, or is there more information? And I assume you're running latest Confluent Platform on Linux?

Comment: @OneCricketeer There is one more error line: "ERROR Failed to clean up log for _schemas-0 in dir /mnt/c/Users/Username/Desktop/Big_Data/confluent-6.0.0/kafka-logs due to IOException (kafka.server.LogDirFailureChannel)
java.io.IOException: Invalid argument" and also two warnings: "WARN [ReplicaManager broker=0] Stopping serving replicas in dir /mnt/c/Users/Username/Desktop/Big_Data/confluent-6.0.0/kafka-logs (kafka.server.ReplicaManager)" and "WARN [ReplicaManager broker=0] Broker 0 stopped fetcher for partitions __consumer_offsets-22, ... (all of the 50 offsets are then listed)"

Comment: @OneCricketeer I am running the latest confluent platform version - version 6.0.0. Im a Windows User so I have enables the "Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL)"-Feature, installed Ubuntu and I am running the Platform on the Windows Subsystem. I am using WSL 1 because WSL 2 caused some problems with the network connectivity.

Comment: So, the `_schemas` topic could be the issue, which is related to the registry, but I also don't think you need WSL since Kafka and Zookeeper have their own Windows start scripts

Comment: @OneCricketeer I now started Kafka and Zookeeper with the Windows start scripts and started the Schema Registry with the .sh script (because Windows is not supported). Now - as far as I can tell, as I just tested a little bit so far - everything seems to work fine! So it might be a Problem with WSL but the behavior still seems strange to me. Thank you very much, OneCricketeer!